# Using nanoframework on the NUCLEO-F746ZG

Tags: stm32, nanoframework

I would like to experiment with the .net nanoframework. An initial test on an ESP32 was successful, but that's not really the platform I'm interested in. Meanwhile, I have a NUCLEO-F746ZG on my desk for further testing.

https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F746ZG/

This board should also be supported as a 'community' board:

https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/community-targets/st-nucleo144-f746zg.html

When installing the nanoframework on the board, I get the following feedback:

```
PS C:\###> nanoff --target ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG --update
.NET nanoFramework Firmware Flasher v2.4.30+cdac7a25ca
Copyright (C) 2019 .NET Foundation and nanoFramework project contributors


Trying to find ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG in stable repository...Not found
Trying to find ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG in community targets repository...OK
Extracting ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG-1.8.1.8.zip...OK

Updating to 1.8.1.8


Connected to JTAG device with ID 0668FF495087534867043936

Device: STM32F74x/STM32F75x
Board: NUCLEO-F746ZG
CPU: Cortex-M7
Device ID: 0x449


******************************************* WARNING ***************************************
It seems that the firmware image that's about to be used isn't the appropriate one for the
target connected. But this doesn't necessarily mean that it won't work.
*******************************************************************************************

Flashing device...
nanoBooter.hex
nanoCLR.hex
Flashing completed...
Reset MCU on device... OK
PS C:\###>
```

The warning indicates that it would not be the right board, but in my experience it should be.  Why would it indicate that this might be the wrong board, which board would be correct?

Next, it fails to make contact with the board. Only the COM port of the debug adapter is found and there is no response to that.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the last part of the warning: "But this doesn't necessarily mean that it won't work."
There is a sanity check on the firmware package name vs the target connected.
You can skip the check/warning by adding the `--nofitcheck`.

See [here](https://github.com/nanoframework/nanoFirmwareFlasher#pre-check-if-target-fits-connected-device) for details.

On this target, it's required to connect an USB cable on the user USB connector. See the now on the readme [here](https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-Community-Targets/tree/main/ChibiOS/ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG#flashing-and-debugging).

Comment: While programming with the --nofitcheck flag, the warning no longer came up. So that looks fine.

With the firmware loaded, I still can't get a connection. The green power LED at the USB port is on, but Windows does not show an additional COM port. On the COM port of the debug adapter, the nanoframework is also not found.

Could it be that something still needs to be connected to establish the connection?

Comment: If you connect USB cables on both connectors doesn't it show up in VS?? Have you tried to rescan on the device explorer toolbar? (recycle icon)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had already tried this. But in Visual Studio the list remains empty. With two different evaluation boards I get no contact via USB (both USB cables are connected).

Comment: You better raise an issue on the project github then: https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues so it can be looked at.